# Compiler Error C2664 when spawning a typed actor

Tags: visual-c++, c++-actor-framework

I'm getting a compiler error with the following code, slightly modified from one of the examples provided by the C++ Actor Framework. The error description is:

```
'void caf::intrusive_ptr_release(caf::ref_counted *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'caf::typed_actor<caf::typed_mpi<caf::detail::type_list<plus_atom,int,int>,caf::detail::type_list<result_atom,int>,caf::detail::empty_type_list>,caf::typed_mpi<caf::detail::type_list<minus_atom,int,int>,caf::detail::type_list<result_atom,int>,caf::detail::empty_type_list>> ' to 'caf::ref_counted *'   include\caf\intrusive_ptr.hpp   70
```

Here is the source code (again, modified from a C++ Actor Framework example):

```
#include "caf/all.hpp"

using namespace caf;

using plus_atom = atom_constant<atom("plus")>;
using minus_atom = atom_constant<atom("minus")>;
using result_atom = atom_constant<atom("result")>;

using calculator_type = typed_actor<replies_to<plus_atom, int, int>::with<result_atom, int>,
                                    replies_to<minus_atom, int, int>::with<result_atom, int>>;

calculator_type::behavior_type typed_calculator(calculator_type::pointer)
{
    return
    {
        [](plus_atom, int x, int y)
        {
            return std::make_tuple(result_atom::value, x + y);
        },
        [](minus_atom, int x, int y)
        {
            return std::make_tuple(result_atom::value, x - y);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    spawn_typed<calculator_type>(typed_calculator);
    shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the templated spawn_typed call requires that an implementing class be referenced as in the following example:

```
#include "caf/all.hpp"

using namespace caf;

using plus_atom = atom_constant<atom("plus")>;
using minus_atom = atom_constant<atom("minus")>;
using result_atom = atom_constant<atom("result")>;

using calculator_type = typed_actor<replies_to<plus_atom, int, int>::with<result_atom, int>,
                                    replies_to<minus_atom, int, int>::with<result_atom, int>>;

class typed_calculator_class : public calculator_type::base
{
protected:
    behavior_type make_behavior() override
    {
        return
        {
            [](plus_atom, int x, int y)
            {
                return std::make_tuple(result_atom::value, x + y);
            },
            [](minus_atom, int x, int y)
            {
                return std::make_tuple(result_atom::value, x - y);
            }
        };
    }
};

int main()
{
    spawn_typed<typed_calculator_class>();
    shutdown();
}
```

Alternatively, to use a non-class based typed actor, simply omit the templating argument from the original code:

```
spawn_typed(typed_calculator);
```